How to select specific python library for an executable?
I have an executable which loads /lib64/libpython3.so at runtime. (I am on fedora 40 right now). As far as I can tell this library loads my default python version installed, currently this links to libpython3.12.so.1.0. The binary I am trying to execute does not like this new version though, so I have to run it on python 3.9. I can install an old interpreter via dnf install python3.9, however it does not ship with the top level libpython3.so (this is another package python3-libs). I can install usr/bin/python3 via alternatives however I am unsure on how to achieve the same thing for the library.
Any ideas how to get this working?
I also tried conda but this does not work either.
